# How can I Check How Many Years, Months and Days Left From Predefined Date using Current Date in oop php mysql

Tags: php, date

I have a predefined date from mysql database query and I want to know how many Years, Months and Days left from the predefined Date using a conditional statement.
Here is what I have tried but the output is not accurate so someone should please help me out.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$edate = new DateTime("{$floor_end}");
$interval = $edate->diff($date);
if ($edate < $date){
echo  $interval->y . " Year(s), " . $interval->m." Month(s), ".$interval->d." Day(s) Left";
}else{
echo "Floor Work Time Has Finished";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly compare 2 `DateTime` object like that. Since you already have the interval object you can get the number of days between 2 DateTime to check

```
$date = new DateTime();
$edate = new DateTime("2030-01-01");
$interval = $edate->diff($date);
if ($interval->d > 0) {
    echo  $interval->y . " Year(s), " . $interval->m." Month(s), ".$interval->d." Day(s) Left";
} else {
    echo "Floor Work Time Has Finished";
}
```

Output:

```
9 Year(s), 4 Month(s), 0 Day(s) Left
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Though the if statement is outputting as expected but my problem here is the else statement part is not displaying even though the endate is set to current day which is today. The if statement is showing 0 Years, 0 Months, 0 Days Left thereby eliminating the else segment part of it

Comment: Then just change the if condition to `$interval->d > 0`, I'll update my answer